# Looking for fast image editor to add text, marks to screenshots

Tags: screenshot, image-editing

I am trying to find a fast tool the edit screenshots already taken with marks, text and rectangles ...
Something like lightshot but for screens already taken.

**Edit:**

[Lightshot link](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)? Also a screenshot tool but with an easy editor incorporated.